# Ubuntu internet connectivity problem after updating to Ubuntu 20.04.2

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

I recently updated to Ubuntu 20.04.2 from 20.04 LTS version. After updating it, the LAN(Ethernet) connection symbol always shows even when I am not connected to internet. I use internet via my smartphone hotspot/tethering, which is not working due to this. There is no issue when I try to connect to internet in Windows. I couldn't figure out what exactly is the problem. Can anyone help me to solve it?

NOTE: I also had proton VPN installed in my Ubuntu before updating. It had once crashed before updating my Ubuntu. I also suspect that it may have something to do with it.

Attached image below :
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5qIO.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q34W.jpg)

Comment: Similar issue here. I think its related to protonvpn as well. I only have internet connection now when connected to protonvpn--once I disconnect, there's no connection, regardless of network I'm on.

Comment: SO is for programming questions only, so OS/networking support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). You can ask on [ubuntu.se] instead.